# Не перебрасывает на другую страницу JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Я сделал форму, которая должна после ввода города пользователя и нажатия на кнопку, показывать объявления Авито о продаже попугаев в его городе.
Чтобы это сделать, мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы ссылка изменялась в зависимости от города + переводилось в транслит и в нижний регистр. Но при нажатии на кнопку НИЧЕГО не происходит. Форма обнуляется. В консоли нет ошибок. Что мне делать?

```js
function translit(word) {
  var answer = '';
  var converter = {
    'а': 'a',
    'б': 'b',
    'в': 'v',
    'г': 'g',
    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',
    'ё': 'e',
    'ж': 'zh',
    'з': 'z',
    'и': 'i',
    'й': 'y',
    'к': 'k',
    'л': 'l',
    'м': 'm',
    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',
    'п': 'p',
    'р': 'r',
    'с': 's',
    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',
    'ф': 'f',
    'х': 'h',
    'ц': 'c',
    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',
    'щ': 'sch',
    'ь': '',
    'ы': 'y',
    'ъ': '',
    'э': 'e',
    'ю': 'yu',
    'я': 'ya',

    'А': 'A',
    'Б': 'B',
    'В': 'V',
    'Г': 'G',
    'Д': 'D',
    'Е': 'E',
    'Ё': 'E',
    'Ж': 'Zh',
    'З': 'Z',
    'И': 'I',
    'Й': 'Y',
    'К': 'K',
    'Л': 'L',
    'М': 'M',
    'Н': 'N',
    'О': 'O',
    'П': 'P',
    'Р': 'R',
    'С': 'S',
    'Т': 'T',
    'У': 'U',
    'Ф': 'F',
    'Х': 'H',
    'Ц': 'C',
    'Ч': 'Ch',
    'Ш': 'Sh',
    'Щ': 'Sch',
    'Ь': '',
    'Ы': 'Y',
    'Ъ': '',
    'Э': 'E',
    'Ю': 'Yu',
    'Я': 'Ya'
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
    if (converter[word[i]] == undefined) {
      answer += word[i];
    } else {
      answer += converter[word[i]];
    }
  }

  return answer;
}

let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search');
searchBtn.onclick = function() {
  let userCity = document.getElementById('city').value;
  userCity = translit(userCity);
  userCity = userCity.toLowerCase();
  document.location.replace(`https://avito.ru/${userCity}/ptitsy?q=попугаи`);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <h1 class="form_title">Поиск объявлений о продаже попугаев</h1>
  <div class="form_grup">
    <input class="form_input" id="city" placeholder="Ваш город">
  </div>
  <button class="form_button" type="submit" id="search">Искать птиц!</button>
</form>
```

пробовал как угодно

Answer (score 2):

замените

```
searchBtn.onclick = function() {
```

на

```
searchBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

А вообще, зачем тут тогда кнопка сабмита формы и сама форма, если это никак не используется? Почему не обычные поля и не просто кнопка?

Comment: спасибо) извините, я просто 2 дня в js

Comment: @ЛёхаВайти если ответ решает Вашу проблему, обозначьте его верным, нажав на галочку

Answer (score 0):

У button вместо `type="submit"` поставьте `type="button"`.